# Django django.db.backends logger and debugging

Tags: python, django, debugging, logging, django-1.8

I am trying to profile a part of my code to reduce the number of queries run against the database, so I configured the following logger which supposedly logs every single raw SQL query that is executed against the database:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console']
        }
    }
}
```

I am debugging said block of code line by line, to slowly inspect the queries that are being logged. The problem is that PyCharm's debugger is evaluating the involved `QuerySet`s, therefore running queries against the database and skewing my analysis.

Is there any way I can configure the debugger so it doesn't automatically evaluate variables? Or essentially any other way I can analyze what raw queries each line of code produces?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late for the show but anyway...

There is a package named django-silk which offers great possibilities to analyse db queries, performance metrics etc. of your django appplication.

https://github.com/jazzband/django-silk